# Is it correct to say "Cut the rope with a knife with your mouth"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I know that both "**with**" and "**by**" can be used to say how something is done. After "**with**", we use an object and after "**by**" we use a method.

For example, "*I cut the cake with a knife*" and "*I cut the cake by using a knife*"

If we don't have a knife, we might say "*I cut the cake with my hand*" and "*I cut the cake by hand*".

Now, a man's hands and legs got tied together but his mouth was free. There was a knife next to him and he had to use his mouth to take hold of the knife to cut the rope.

So, there were 3 things involved: **the rope, the knife and the mouth**.

I can say lengthily like this "**Hold the knife with your mouth and then cut the rope with the knife**".

Can we make that sentence shorter by saying  "**Cut the rope with a knife with your mouth**"?

Comment: You can't cut a cake with your hand because your hand isn't sharp; you would have to _break/tear it apart_. Doing something 'by hand' usually means 'not using a machine'. You would have to grip the handle of a knife between your teeth in order to cut something with it, so we would say _with a knife held between your teeth_.

Comment: Hold the knife in your mouth to cut the rope. Short.

Comment: Such a contrived bizarre situation, only you could have come up with it! Have you ever tried cutting meat with a knife clasped **in** your mouth?  Would you grip it vertically (?)  **between your teeth**?

Comment: If this is a scene from a movie, it usually involves two people, the one hostage cuts free the other hostage by either kneeling or bending down to reach the rope. Perhaps a razor would be able to cut through a rope, maybe a knife with a really really sharp blade. I sincerely think this question belongs in [Movies and TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) : Has anyone, in a movie or TV show, ever freed their hands tied up with a rope **using a knife** grasped in their mouth? P.S In movies and maybe in real life, hostage's hands are often tied behind their back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can express what you are trying to express but you would not express it as you have.  Since putting a knife in your mouth and using that knife to cut a rope is not a *common* situation, you will need to provide a bit more information in your statement to prevent your reader from getting lost and confused.  You would say something like,

> Use your mouth to cut the rope with the knife.

Saying, *Use your mouth*, immediately clarifies what you are requesting.  In the situation you describe, context will help clear up any ambiguity in the above statement.

Answer (score 2):

No, **with a knife with your mouth** doesn't make any sense.  If someone said that, I would say, "Huh?  Do you want me to use a knife, or do you want me to use my mouth?"  It really just doesn't make any sense because the man is not cutting the rope with his mouth.